# Does VirtualBox's .ova appliance creator preserve port forwarding?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, port-forwarding, appliance

If I create a virtual machine in VirtualBox, set software on the machine to listen to port 1234, and configure VirtualBox to forward traffic on port 1234 to the guest, and then export it as an appliance, does the exported file, on import, forward port 1234, or will users of the appliance need to manually specify to forward traffic to the guest?

TIA,

Comment: It does preserve the port forwarding rules when you export it into an .ova appliance. I was curious so I just tested it myself.

Comment: Thank you; please state it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does VirtualBox's .ova appliance creator preserve port forwarding?

Yes, it will preserve the port forwarding rules you have in place when you export the appliance into an .ova file.

I tested this myself by creating a couple port forwarding rules on one of my virtual machines:

[image]

Then exported the appliance:

[image]

And then imported the .ova file into a new virtual machine and verified that the port forwarding rules were still in place:

[image]